# Dimension SST Printer Broken parts

Tags: replacement-parts

My company has an old Dimension SST printer that is out of commission due to a few broken pieces. 
I have contacted the Stratsys folk and they won't do anything until we purchase a multi-thousand dollar service policy. 
I also have a Makerbot that I can use to create spare parts however, can't find pictures of the original configuration. 
The broken pieces are the Toggle Bar and Z Foam Sensor and whatever parts used to hold them in place on the head. Toggle Bar circled in red [image] View of my printer where the toggle bar used to be [image]

Two Questions:
Does anyone know of a location to purchase spare parts? 
Does anyone have detailed pictures (360 view) of the print head they are willing to share so I can recreate the parts/attachments.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Does [this PDF](http://www.rnd-tech.com/media/fdm-pdfs/dimension-1200-es.pdf), page 61 help?

Comment: Unfortunately i need the backside view of that image. Thank you for doing some digging!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how no one has been able to find a solution yet and I'm not familiar with your machine, I would recommend reverse engineering the part to the best of your abilities. If you don't have the right tools, try finding a local machine shop and ask if you can use their measuring equipment. Sometimes you might get lucky and they will have something more intuitive than callipers, such as a CNC CMM or CMM Arm. As far as acquiring the part, try asking the machine shop if they can produce it, or get it 3D printed via 3D Hubs, MakeXYZ, or some other peer printing service.

I'm sorry I don't have a more direct solution, but hopefully it at least a general sense of what options you may have.